# get html from a div and show them on a other page

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

i am struggling with the following :

I have a html mainpage , on this page i have a column with a "read more"section , so a couple of lines tekst from a news message from a html page called News .

when there is new news , i have to update the "read more"section by hand .

Is it possible with Jquery and ajax to update the "read more"section on page load.

maybe you guys have a better way to do something like this , ore is there some $ code i dont know

hope you can help me

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [loading page fragments using `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load). Depending on your page's markup, something like this on the main page should work.

```
// Grab the first div in the #news element on
// the news.html page and jam it into #recent
$('#recent').load('/news.html #news div:first');
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/SLx9c](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/SLx9c/)**

Comment: Fantastic , this is working , thank you , i tried to limit the .load , (i only want a sort of excerpt just 35 words from the /news.html #news) with {limit:35} but than didnt do the trick , you have also a sollustion for that ?   Cheers